# sbt test-only not picking up jvm option when forking a jvm for tests

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following lines in my build.sbt

```
fork := true

javaOptions in run += "-Dmy.environment=local"

javaOptions in test += "-Dmy.environment=local"
```

This works totally fine when I use the "test" command in sbt and when my code checks the jvm system settings for my.environment, it finds the correct value (i.e., "local").

The problem that I am having is that when I run "test-only org.whatever.SomeTest" in this case the my.environment key isn't in the jvm system settings.  Specifically, System.getProperty("my.environment") is null whereas it was "local" when I just ran "test".

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You are likely hitting [#975: regression: fork in test doesn't work anymore](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/975), which is currently under review. Try:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dmy.environment=local"
```